# after upgrade to python2.6 and ubuntu 9.0, django admin does not load css even though admin media is properly configured

Tags: django, django-admin

basically i upgraded ubuntu to juanty, and with it came python2.6 so i decided to take the chance and make django work with it. i re-svn'd django into dist-packages, and made sure to properly sym-link my admin media.  Note that i'm not using apache, rather just the django development server.

when i load up the admin the css seems to not take effect, when i view source it is calling the proper files and i even go ahead and load these files in the browser and they load properly.

any ideas as to what i've done wrong? i'm thinking it has to do with using the latest revision of django.

-------------Edit--------------------

to answer your questions below:

I am not running apache, i'm serving static files using django and i've tried loading the files from the browser and they work fine.

i did this in my settings file

```
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/static/admin_media/'
```

i symlinked from my static folder admin_media > /usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/media/

this is really stumping me as i think i've done everything right.

------------Edit------------

heres a sample of my urls.py

```
(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
```

what i've recalled is that before (in ubuntu 8 & probably an older svn revision of django) i didn't configure anyting in my settings or symlin anything from my static folder and it worked just fine with the default /media/ - is there somewhere where it is symlinked automatically for the admin?

------Edit-------------------
This is most likely a bug with the svn version, as after this i tried on my windows machine and i get the same thing.  the css files are linked properly but are not imported. instead when i click on them it downloads the files.  permission issue anyone?

help, as the admin doesn't look as nice without the css formating.

Comment: What does your urls.py look like? I will update my post with an example.

Comment: "I've tried loading the files from the browser and they work fine". If that's the case, then there must be something up with the urls that the admin is generating for fetching the files.

Comment: Try changing the ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX to '/media/' (or another path not under '/static/'.

Comment: it was originally to /media/ but when that didn't work i changed it to under static thinking it wasn't being served

Answer (score -1, accepted):

wow, i don't want to come across as an answer spammer for answering my own questions but... nobody else seemed to answer the questions and i then tend to figure them out by myself.  ugghh..

anways the answer to the above is simple, quite simple

since i had created the above django projects using an older version of django and not the latest svn version, you need to overwrite or delete the old admin media directory under static and the admin templates.  in my case i just deleted the admini media and admin templates and voila ... the admin was back!!!

can't believe i hadn't tought of that before.

Answer (score 0):

I am using python 2.6.2 on jaunty and the latest django svn reversion (rev. 10857) and don't have any problems.

Can you supply more details? For example, what did you set in your settings.py, how did you configure your urls.py, are you using django to serve the media files, what is the output from the debug server when you load the admin interface, do you get any errors, etc.

Have you tried requesting the files directly or used firebug (checking for 404's and the like)?

*Edit:*

A little unrelated but, you may want to make your project more portable/reusable by using relative paths.

```
#settings.py
import os

PROJECT_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

DEBUG = True
SERVE_MEDIA = DEBUG

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'static')
MEDIA_URL = '/static/'
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/media/'
```

Comment: i added the static part of my urls.py as i assume thats what you need to see

Answer (score 0):

Are you running under Apache? Depending on what earlier version of Ubuntu you upgraded from, some Apache configs might have changed. I have a vague recollection of having had a problem upgrading from dapper to 8.10 that was solved by adding a  block to /etc/apache2/httpd.conf

Comment: No, not running apache this problem occurs only when i'm developing on my ubuntu desktop, when i upload to my production server that runs apache it works just fine.